# WooCommerce: get a shipping methods by Country code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to get the shipping available methods by country code that giving in the request, in the above code I'm facing an issue/conflict

That the available locations can be both a `country` or a `continent` so I need to check if this country code is a part of some continent.

the problem is with the first zone I get all methods in all zones not just within the first ( the callback return ).

The second zone which has the continents/countries ( rest of the world ) I get no issues with it but as far I guess that's because its the end of the loop. ( as I have two zones for now )

```php
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
    register_rest_route(
        "test-api/v1",
        "shipping-cost",
        array(
            'callback' => function ($req) {
                $country_code = $req->get_param('country_code');
                $quantity = $req->get_param('quantity');

                $shipping_cost = 0;
                $methodes = [];


                if (class_exists('WC_Shipping_Zones')) {
                    $all_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();


                    if (!empty($all_zones)) {
                        foreach ($all_zones as $zone) {
                            if (!empty($zone['zone_locations'])) {
                                foreach ($zone['zone_locations'] as $location) {

                                    $wc_contries = new WC_Countries();
                                    $continent_code = $wc_contries->get_continent_code_for_country($country_code);


                                    if ($country_code === $location->code || $continent_code === $location->code) {
                                        if (!empty($zone['shipping_methods'])) {
                                            $shipping_method_ctrl = new WC_REST_Shipping_Zone_Methods_Controller();

                                            foreach ($zone['shipping_methods'] as $flat_rate) {

                                                $shipping_method = $shipping_method_ctrl->prepare_item_for_response($flat_rate, $req);
                                                $methodes[] = (object) $shipping_method;

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                return $methodes;
            }

        )
    );
});
```

Comment: if you have found a solution can you please share?

Comment: I have added the final code below as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer: ( adding `break` with the number of the array want it to be stop )

```php
Register_rest_route(
    "kefan-api/v1",
    "shipping-cost",
    array(
        'callback' => function ($req) {
            $country_code = $req->get_param('country_code');
            $methodes = [];


            if (class_exists('WC_Shipping_Zones')) {
                $all_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();


                if (!empty($all_zones)) {
                    foreach ($all_zones as $zone) {
                        if (!empty($zone['zone_locations'])) {
                            foreach ($zone['zone_locations'] as $location) {

                                $wc_contries = new WC_Countries();
                                $continent_code = $wc_contries->get_continent_code_for_country($country_code);


                                if ($country_code === $location->code || $continent_code === $location->code) {
                                    if (!empty($zone['shipping_methods'])) {
                                        $shipping_method_ctrl = new WC_REST_Shipping_Zone_Methods_Controller();

                                        foreach ($zone['shipping_methods'] as $flat_rate) {

                                            $shipping_method = $shipping_method_ctrl->prepare_item_for_response($flat_rate, $req);
                                            $methodes[] = (object) $shipping_method;

                                        }
                                        break 2;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return $methodes;
        }

    )
);
```